# service not working between two controllers getting undefined

Tags: angularjs

I am showing employee record using AngularJS. I am using two  views to show data, I am using two views `emp-box.htm` and its respective controller(`empController`) and in this controller `employeeBoxController` I am fetching data from service, I want the result which is obtained in `employeeBoxController` to be used in `empController` and show in view (`emp-list.htm`), I created a service `eService`

```
app.service('dataService',function() {

  var s = {};

  this.setData = function(data,key) {
    s[key]=data;
  },
  this.getData = function(key) {
    return s[key];
  }
  this.hello = function() {
    return 'hello';
  }
})
```

for fetching result and setting data in `employeeBoxController` and getting in `empController` but when I fetch the data using `console.log(dataService.getData('result'));` in empController i get `undefined`

The `employeeBoxController` is

```
app.controller("employeeBoxController", ['$scope', 'employeeService', 
  'dataService', function($scope, employeeService, dataService) {
  $scope.getEmployeeDetails = function(eid) {
    $scope.isLoading = false;
    employeeService.getDetails($scope.eid).then(function(result) {
      dataService.setData(result, 'result');
      $scope.isLoading = true;
      console.log(dataService.getData('result'));
    })
  }
}])
```

The `empController` is :-

```
app.controller("empController", ['$scope', 'employeeService', 'dataService', 
  function($scope, employeeService, dataService) {

    $scope.result = dataService.getData('result');
    //console.log(dataService.hello());

    console.log(dataService.getData('result'));

    console.log(dataService.hello());
  }
])
```

The service class  `employeeService` is :-

```
  app.config(["employeeServiceProvider",function(employeeServiceProvider){
      employeeServiceProvider.config('http://localhost:8080/pos');
  }]);

  app.provider("employeeService",function(){
    var myurl='';

    this.config=function(eurl){
      myurl=eurl;
    }

    this.$get=['$http','$log',function($http,$log){
      var employeeobj={};
      employeeobj.getDetails=function(eid){
        return $http.get(myurl+'/getEmployees/'+eid);
    }

  return employeeobj;
    }];
  });
```

`emp-box.htm` is:-

```
    <div>
  Enter the id: <input type="text" ng-model="eid"/>
  <button ng-click="getEmployeeDetails()">show</button>
   </div>
   emp-list.htm is:-
       <div class="panel panel-primary">
       <div class="panel-body" style="text-align:center; margin:0 auto">
      <h3>Employee Data</h3>
      </div>
     </div>
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-body">
      <!--  <div ng-show="!isLoading" style="color:red">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>Loading...
      </div>-->
     <table class="table table-hover">
     <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>empno</th>
      <th>salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="oemp in result.data">

      <td>{{oemp.eid}}</td>
      <td>{{oemp.name}}</td>
      <td>{{oemp.empno}}</td>
      <td>{{oemp.sal}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

    </table>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Does setData return something ?

Comment: no setData is setting the data,its not return anything

Comment: But doesn't data contain anything? Just trying to figure

Comment: i am setting the data value dataService.setData(result, 'result'); check above code

Comment: Have you made sure that `employeeService.getDetails()` actually returns data? if its an `$http/Ajax` call, the data would be in `result.data`.

Comment: It seems like `empController`'s `dataService.getData('result')` call happening before `employeeService.getDetails($scope.eid)` ajax gets completed..

Comment: Do both controllers "actions" setting data -> reading date belongs to the same page? I mean, if you execute the code in two separate controllers referenced the same view (with twice ng-controller data-attributes) $scope may not get updated. (because it's digest cycle is done and no changes to the reference have been detected). Please post your template files

Comment: @sajal i have added the employeeService class and its returning result.data in console.

Comment: Can you create a plunk/fiddle with your code? This will help in debugging quickly.

Comment: @YuriBlanc i have added the templatefiles

Comment: i debuged the code empController is executing first before the ajax call happens as mentioned above by @Pankaj Parkar so data in empController is undefined , i am not sure how multiple view are working i cilck on button then function getEmployeeDetails() is called and ajax call happens but how the controller empController is intantiated first –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand you're trying to cache your API results in another service, so you don't have to call the API again in another controller. Also, `empController` is executed first, and when you're doing `dataService.getData('result')` the API response of setting it isn't received yet which in turn is called from another service. I would suggest you combine these 2 services, so that instead of caching the exact values in service, you can cache the API call itself, and in case where cache doesn't contain your data, make an API call and cache it.

Here's something I'd make, say `CacheAPIService`.

```
app.factory('CacheAPIService', ['$http', function($http) {
  var cache = {};
  return {
    get: function(api) {
     if(angular.isUndefined(cache[api])) {
       cache[api] =  $http.get(api); //storing in cache while making API call
     }
     return cache[api]; //Return from cache
    },
    clear: function(api) {
        delete cache[api];
    }
  }
}]);
```

So, whenever you need to make an cache an API  call, use this service in addition to making API call it'll also cache it. And, if it is already cached, no new API call is made. Benefits is you'll never run into cases where it return's `undefined`, as you are returning promise.

In your 1st controller, updated code becomes:

```
app.controller("employeeBoxController", ['$scope', 'CacheAPIService', function($scope, CacheAPIService) {
  $scope.getEmployeeDetails = function(eid) {
    $scope.isLoading = true;
    var endpoint = 'api/endpoint/'+$scope.eid;    //Replace with your API endpoint
    CacheAPIService.get(endpoint).then(function(result) {
      $scope.isLoading = false;
      console.log(dataService.getData('result'));
    })
  }
}]);
```

Here, 1st API call is made and is cached. Take a look at your other controller:

```
app.controller("empController", ['$scope', 'CacheAPIService', function($scope, CacheAPIService) {
  CacheAPIService.get(endpoint).then(function(data) {
    var endpoint = 'api/endpoint/'+$scope.eid; //your API endpoint
    console.log('data =', data);
  });

}]);
```

Here, you still use the same service, but it'll be cached, and if not cached, it'll make API call and cache that promise. Here I've directly used API endpoint as key for storing in cache. This way you don't have to provide unique keys every time, as endpoint itself is unique.

Note that in cases where you want to delete cached data, when making POST or PUT call, you can call `CacheAPIService.clear(apiEndpoint)` to clear details from cache.

Comment: this is good approach to cache the api but i am getting undefined for the eid which i set in employeeBoxController and when i try to use in $scope.eid

Comment: This way you create a cache service that also implements rest logics to get data...

Answer (score 0):

$http.get will return a promise.
To correctly set data to dataService:

```
 employeeService.getDetails($scope.eid).then(function(result) {
      dataService.setData(result.data, 'result'); // note .data
      $scope.isLoading = true;
      console.log(dataService.getData('result'));
    })
```

Storing the promise in your "cache" service is not the best option.

I expect getEmployeeDetails() function is going to route to empController, so if you still store $promise in your service as you stated, you can do.

```
    dataService.getData('result').then(function(result){
        $scope.result = result.data;
  });
```

When $scope.result is set to $scope,  ng-repeat will start iterating over.

With the first change suggested, you just don't need to touch empController but just the ng-repeat directive  emp-list.html with:

```
<tr ng-repeat="oemp in result">
```

Refactor the http call with factory recipe and $resource.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

That is easier and quicker than writing providers.

Comment: i debuged the code  empController is executing first before the ajax call happens as mentioned above by @Pankaj Parkar so data in empController is undefined  , i am not sure how multiple view are working  i cilck on button then function getEmployeeDetails() is called and ajax call happens but how the controller empController is intantiated first

Comment: The fact is that the $http service is acutally calling the server endpoint with an async request. Of course you'll get the execution of the controller first (always) but promise are supposed to work that way. Angular anyway, will watch your scope variable and when feed with data, will show/parse it. i Suggest you this reading. http://robotlolita.me/2015/11/15/how-do-promises-work.html

Comment: how do i store the promise in my dataService,should i again make a new ajax call using $http.get

Comment: The service can store values (cache) but also functions.. Just add a function inside the service that do your httpRequest. If will be available everywhere once injected.. or better, use the factory recipe with $resource you can find in angular docs. This concern logic separation. Storing the promise into a vector right after call then is a bad idea.